# Gridview handling null

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I need to be able to distinguish between NULLs and empty data in my gridview on both read and write, and to use autogenerated columns as the gridview will be used for multiple datasets.

I attempted to create a "nullGridView" control as follows. I put the code file into my App_Code directory.

```
Namespace Xcontrol
    Partial Public Class nullGridView
        Inherits System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView

        Protected Overrides Function CreateAutoGeneratedColumn(ByVal fieldProperties As AutoGeneratedFieldProperties) As AutoGeneratedField

            ' Create an AutoGeneratedField object. 
            Dim field As New AutoGeneratedField(fieldProperties.DataField)

            ' Set the properties of the AutoGeneratedField using 
            ' the values from the AutoGeneratedFieldProperties  
            ' object contained in the fieldProperties parameter. 
            CType(field, IStateManager).TrackViewState()
            field.HeaderText = fieldProperties.Name
            field.SortExpression = fieldProperties.Name
            field.ReadOnly = fieldProperties.IsReadOnly
            field.DataType = fieldProperties.Type
            field.NullDisplayText = "NULL"

            Return field

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

In my .aspx file, I have references

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Xcon" Namespace="Xcontrol" %>
...
<Xcon:nullGridView ID="gv2" runat="server"></Xcon:nullGridView>
```

During design mode, all is well and intellisense displays all the properties of the Gridview.
But when I try to compile, I get "Type 'Xcontrol.nullGridView' is not defined.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've had many times where, for whatever reason, when I create the file in the App_Code folder, it doesn't compile.  What I found that works is to move the file in question out of that folder and onto the root, or wherever really, and then all of a sudden it will magically compile.  Then you can move it back to the App_Code folder.  All compilations should work from there on out.  It's a weird one that's for sure.

As far as understanding *why* it doesn't work inside the App_Code folder, I've found this article to be very helpful:

[**App_Code folder doesn’t work with Web Application Projects (WAPs)**](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)

You might just be better off creating a ***Controls*** or ***CustomControls*** folder on your root and placing the file(s) there.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I tried your suggestion - I created a "System Controls" folder and moved the file to it, with a build action of compile.  But now it doesn't show up at all when I attempt to Register the file (that is, if I type <Xcon: to start a tag then nothing shows up).  Do you have a working example that perhaps you could post?  What I'm interested in is, if you put the control definition into a .vb file in a folder, how do you then reference it in the aspx file so that it looks like a regular control.

Comment: I would try creating it as an actual control by creating a new ascx file with nothing in the design file (ascx) but the page directive that points to your code-behind file (ascx.vb).  I would think that should get you the reference you need.

Comment: Thanks again.  I actually solved this by putting a placeholder into the .aspx file, then creating the control dynamically in code-behind and adding it as a child control to the placeholder.  That works perfectly, except that the overridden CreateAutoGeneratedColumn doesn't fire - but that will the be the subject of another posting.